# How to get rid of nested column names in Pandas from group by aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following code that finds the total and unique sales for each employee using a group by with `Employee_id` and aggregation with `Customer_id`.

```
Sales.groupby('Employee_id').agg({
    'Customer_id': [
        ('total_sales', 'count'),
        ('unique_sales', 'nunique')
]})
```

It is important to know that I will perform aggregations with other columns as well, but so far this is all I have written. So if you have a proposed solution, I ask that you please consider that in case it makes a difference.

While this does exactly what I want in terms of computing total and unique sales for each employee and creating two columns, it creates nested column names. So the column names look like, [('Customer_id', 'total_sales'), ('Customer_id', 'unique_sales')], which I don't want. Is there any way to easily get rid of the nested part to only include ['total_sales', 'unique_sales'], or is the easiest thing to just rename the columns once I have finished everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply rename the columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2018)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
result = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [('D','count'),('E','nunique')],
                              'C': [('F','first'),('G','max')]})
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)
print(result)
```

Alternatively, you could save the `groupby` object, and use `grouped[col].agg(...)`
to produce sub-DataFrames which can then be `pd.concat`'ed together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2018)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
grouped = df.groupby('A')
result = pd.concat([grouped['B'].agg([('D','count'),('E','nunique')]),
                    grouped['C'].agg([('F','first'),('G','max')])], axis=1)
print(result)
```

both code snippets yield the following (though with columns perhaps in a different order):

```
    D  E  F  G
A             
0  18  8  8  9
1  12  8  6  6
2  14  8  0  8
3  10  9  8  9
4   7  6  3  5
5   8  5  6  7
6   9  7  9  9
7   8  6  4  7
8   8  7  2  9
9   6  5  7  9
```

Overall, I think renaming the columns after-the-fact is the easiest and more readable option.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearly showing both options! I like the first one better :)

Comment: A quick follow-up, do you know how to make the index (A in your example) a column instead of an index?

Comment: Usually you could avoid this problem by using `df.groupby('A', as_index=False)`. This tells `groupby/agg` to return a DataFrame with `A` being a column instead of the index. But in this case, that does not work well since the `A` is placed in the 0th column level which is dropped by `result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)`.

Comment: So instead use `result = result.reset_index()` to move the index into a column. (And by the way, `result.set_index` is the method you would use to do reverse -- moving column(s) into the index.)

Comment: What I like about pandas is it is so intuitive and easy to troubleshoot